# How to save an object with jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

If we save an object with jpa like: `session.persist(student);` 
Does this save as prepared statements? Also, does this avoid the sql injection?

Answer (score 1):

strudent there is an entity, represent one row(with its relation to other table if any), and will generated prepared statement that will avoid sql injection because its wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hibernate will create a prepared statement (and thus prevent SQL injection).